# Analog of OS X caching service on Android

Tags: android, macos, caching, apk, google-play

I read about Apple's Caching Service ([here a link](https://www.apple.com/support/osxserver/cachingservice/)), which is a great idea.

I'd need to know if there's something similar for Android devices, something that caches the APKs downloaded from the Play Store and serves the cached one to the clients.. I googled around and I found nothing useful..

Do you know if there's a server-side service like the Apple one that could work for Android devices?

Thank you in advance..!